# Normal curvature of Veronese embedding

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, comparison-geometry

> Is it true that the Veronese embedding minimize maximal normal curvature among all smooth embeddings $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n\hookrightarrow \mathbb{S}^N$?

**Remarks**

- The [Veronese embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronese_surface) $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n\hookrightarrow \mathbb{S}^{(n+3)\cdot n/2}$ describes a minimal surface. Its induced metric tensor $=2\times$(canonical metric on $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$). It sends geodesics of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ to circles with curvature $\kappa_n=\sqrt{\tfrac{n-1}{n+1}}$ in the sphere; in particular, its normal curvature $\kappa_n$ at every point in every direction.
- The value $\kappa_n$ can be visualized the following way. Suppose $d_n$ is the spherical distance between vertices of inscribed equilateral $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Then $\kappa_n$ is the curvature of spherical circle of radius $d_n/2$. Note that $d_n\to \tfrac\pi2$ and $\kappa_n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.
- I can solve the case $n=2$. In fact any submanifold with normal curvature $<\kappa_2=\tfrac1{\sqrt{3}}$ is diffeomorphic to the standard sphere. (In this case the curvature of the induced metric is $\tfrac14$-pinched; so it is sufficient to show that the submanifold is simply connected.)
- The question is motivated by Gromov's ["Isometric immersions with controlled curvatures"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.06122).